# How to format Excel sheet, to allow import of numerous data sets

Tags: xml, excel, stylesheet

All help appreciated.

I have many excel spread sheets which contain different data sets, though the data sets ( each spreadsheet ) is formatted identically.

Problem : the problem is as I advance the way I wish to interpret the data sets I have to open each of the spreadsheets and change each one in exactly the same way. Very irritating.

Is there a way to format an excel sheet as a "stylesheet" and then import the data sets as XML ? That way I only have to work on updating one sheet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a template on one workbook, save it as a template. Then, when you are in the workbook you want that style to exist add a new sheet from the template. Make sure you delete the other two worksheets in your template so they are not added also.

See:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-excel-templates-HP005229286.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> "change each one in exactly the same way"

Exactly what do you change that need to propogate to other sheets?

Can you record a macro of what you do?  Post your recorded code for help customizing.